# HTML from lambda invoked by Kong has double quotes

Tags: aws-lambda, kong, kong-plugin

I’m trying to return an HTML from a lambda that gets invoked by Kong as a RequestResponse invocation.

This is how the lambda looks like:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  context.succeed('<h2>bleh</h2>')
};
```

This ends up with something like this:
[image]

*Notice the double quotes on the page.*

I’ve explicitly set the content type to HTML in response transformer for this lambda invocation.
I tried sending a byte array instead, and also switched to using the `callback` method instead of `context.succeed`.

How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "is_proxy_integration" configuration that the kong AWS lambda plugin provides helped solved the problem. Check [documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/aws-lambda/#parameters).

This behaves similar to the AWS API gateway integration. Read about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format).

I had to  tweak my lambda to return this instead, which made it work:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  context.succeed({
    statusCode: 200, 
    headers: {'content-type': 'text/html'}, 
    body: "<h1>bleh</h1>"
  });
};
```